# How to select a range of my table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, range

I have a table like this: 
*(Pay attention to the sequence numbers for every word)*

```
// tablename
+---------+----------+
|  word   |  number  |
----------------------
|  jack   |     1    |
|  jack   |     2    |
|  jack   |     3    |
|  ali    |     1    |
|  ali    |     2    |
|  ali    |     3    |
|  ali    |     4    |
|  ali    |     5    |
|  peter  |     1    |
|  peter  |     2    |
|  peter  |     3    |
|  peter  |     4    |
|  raj    |     1    |
|  raj    |     2    |
+---------+----------+
```

Now i need a query to select a range. My range is *(for example)*:

```
// Range Start
select * from tablename where word='ali' and number='2';

// Range End
select * from tablename where word='peter' and number='3';
```

In fact I want below result:

```
+---------+----------+
|  word   |  number  |
----------------------
|  ali    |     2    |
|  ali    |     3    |
|  ali    |     4    |
|  ali    |     5    |
|  peter  |     1    |
|  peter  |     2    |
|  peter  |     3    |
+---------+----------+
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: this range doesn't really make sense from a database standpoint... what makes "peter" occur after "all" aside from the fact that ***you*** wrote them in that order?  The rows in a database don't really have this sort of order natively... they could potentially based on your index, but I don't think an index on the columns you provided would ever order them in this order.

Comment: @Kritner my table has a id column and I have not any problem with sort !

Comment: and if you ordered by the ID column, are the rows in the order that you posted?

Comment: @Kritner yes they are !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to head out but if your data looks like this with the ID column:

```
+---------+----------+----+
|  word   |  number  | ID |
---------------------------
|  jack   |     1    | 1  |
|  jack   |     2    | 2  |
|  jack   |     3    | 3  |
|  ali    |     1    | 4  |
|  ali    |     2    | 5  |
|  ali    |     3    | 6  |
|  ali    |     4    | 7  |
|  ali    |     5    | 8  |
|  peter  |     1    | 9  |
|  peter  |     2    | 10 |
|  peter  |     3    | 11 |
|  peter  |     4    | 12 |
|  raj    |     1    | 13 |
|  raj    |     2    | 14 |
+---------+----------+----+
```

Then you could do this (this is just one way, there are most likely more optimal ways)

```
select *
from table
where id >= (select id from table where word='ali' and number='2')
 and id <= (select id from table where word='peter' and number='3')
```

Comment: The way is clever. Liked !

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Id column, this is a simple way to do what you need

```
SELECT
  word, number 
FROM 
  Test 
WHERE 
  id BETWEEN
    (SELECT id FROM Test WHERE word = 'ali' AND number = '2') AND
    (SELECT id FROM Test WHERE word = 'peter' AND number = '3');
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c199/2) you have a working example in SQLFiddle

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from table 
where (word = 'ali' and number >='2') or (word = 'peter' and number <= '3')
order by word, number
```

Comment: Your code is good only for two diffrent word (something like my example). but for 3 name did not work. How can i select range of jack|2 to peter|4  ?

Comment: where (word >= 'jack' and number >='2') and (word <= 'peter' and number <= '4')

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tablename
where (word = 'ali' and number between '2' and '5') OR
      (word = 'peter' and number between '1' and'3')
order by word, number
```

Comment: You need an order by otherwise you won't get the data in the excpected order.

Comment: Not necessarily. If his table shown has IDs in the sequence it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want your data ordered first by `word`, then by `number`, you could do something like this:

```
select * from table
    where strcmp(concat(word, lpad(number, 5, '0')), concat('ali', lpad(2, 5, '0'))) >= 0
    and strcmp(concat(word, lpad(number, 5, '0')), concat('peter', lpad(3, 5, '0'))) <= 0
    order by word asc, number asc;
```

This takes the two fields, and makes one ASCII string, `nameNNNNN`, to compare with. This will work independent of the sequencing of the record IDs. If your `word` and `number` were set up as a composite index, you could order based upon that and not use the string comparisons and concatenations.

Answer (score 0):

```
    select * from tablename where 
(word = 'ali' and number >= 2) or 
(word = 'peter' and number <= 3);
```

that should yield the result you are looking for, though if you had a primary key that was unique within the table that served as an index you could simply query the table using something like this;

```
select * from tablename where index between x and y;
```

that would obviously suggest that you knew the index values that you needed, though you could get those using some nested conditions like this;

```
    select * from tablename where index between 
(select index from tablename where name = 'ali' and number =2) and 
(select index from tablename where name=peter and number = 5);
```

hope that helps.

Comment: In first you should use `or` instead of `and`, and your code is good only for two diffrent word (something like my example). but for 3 name did not work. How can i select range of jack|2 to peter|4 ?

Comment: that makes sense, in terms of selecting 3 names you'd really want to have an index primary key going on. that way you can select the range based on index instead of specific complex conditions.  the third example of code I gave would work in that case, though you'd need to switch out ali for jack.